# How to use hypen symbols in custom module controller url in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.4, url-rewrite

I have form input where user can enter postcode. When they enter postcode i am redirecting other page (controller url-popup/action/index) and i showing postcode inforation in that page. But i need postcode information page url like this - (our-service/fashion-store/postcode-information).
How can i use hypen symbols in controller url. Thanks

this is my controller.

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. As far as I'm aware only the `frontName` of a route allows dashes in it. You could create a custom router to do this but I think a better way would be to create a setup script that adds entries to the `url_rewrite` table.

The sample code below will install the url rewrite for all the stores you have configured, however it won't automatically add a new URL for any additional stores, you will need to create an observer to do that for you, or manually trigger the setup script again by deleting its entry in the `patch_list` table.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlPersistInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewriteFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class InstallUrlRewrites implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /** @var StoreManagerInterface */
    private $storeManager;
    /** @var UrlRewriteFactory */
    private $urlRewriteFactory;
    /** @var UrlPersistInterface */
    private $urlPersist;
    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param UrlRewriteFactory $urlRewriteFactory
     * @param UrlPersistInterface $urlPersist
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        UrlRewriteFactory $urlRewriteFactory,
        UrlPersistInterface $urlPersist,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->urlRewriteFactory = $urlRewriteFactory;
        $this->urlPersist = $urlPersist;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $urls = [];
        foreach ($this->storeManager->getStores() as $store) {
            $urls[] = $this->urlRewriteFactory->create()->setStoreId($store->getStoreId())
                ->setEntityType('custom')
                ->setRequestPath('our-service/fashion-store/postcode-information')
                ->setTargetPath('controller url-popup/action/index')
                ->setIsAutogenerated(1);
        }
        try {
            $this->urlPersist->replace($urls);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error(sprintf(
                'Error whilst saving custom URL rewrites:',
                $e->getMessage()
            ));
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could manually add the rewrites in `Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites`

Answer (score 1):

You can check this module from m.academy. It should resolve the issues with adding dashes to the controller's URLs

module: https://github.com/markshust/magento2-module-specialrouter

yt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QocA43TIUnI